# Difference of functions inequality

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

In one book on complex analysis I see the following:

> But $f$ is continuous at the point $z$. Hence, for each positive number $\varepsilon$, a positive number $\delta$ exists such that
>   $$\lvert f(s) - f(z)\rvert <\varepsilon \text{ whenever } \lvert s-z \rvert<\delta.$$
>   Consequently, if the point $z+\Delta z$ is close enough to $z$ so that $\lvert \Delta z\rvert < \delta$, then
>   $$\underbrace{\left| \frac{F(z+\Delta z) - F(z)}{\Delta z} \right|}_{(1)} < \underbrace{\frac{1}{\left| \Delta z\right|}\varepsilon\left|\Delta z\right|}_{(2)} =\varepsilon$$
>
> or $F'(z)=f(z)$.

My question is: what property/inequality did the authors use to arrive from (1) to (2)?

Comment: You should define what $F$ is.

Comment: The authors used the definition of $F$. You should write it in your question, we can't read in your mind...

Comment: Is $F$ a integral of $f$ on $z$ to $z+\Delta$? In that case, that is just a matter of estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact
$$ |F(z+\Delta z) - F(z)|=\left|\int_{z}^{z+\Delta z}f(t)dt\right|<\varepsilon\left|\int_{z}^{z+\Delta z}dt\right| <\varepsilon|z+\Delta z-z| =\varepsilon|\Delta z|$$
and the first inequality is due to:

Since $f$ is continuous and $z+\Delta z$ is $\bf \hbox{very very close}$ close to z,  we have $f(t)\leq|f(s)-f(z)|$ whenever $|s-z|<\delta$ and $t\in[z,z+\Delta z]$

Comment: I drew a picture, but I don't see how $f(t)\le \left| f(s)-f(z) \right|$. I drew it like this: take $z$ and $z+\Delta z$ on the $x$-axis, and draw an arbitrary smooth arc from $f(z)$ to $f(z+\Delta z)$. Then the segment $\left| f(s)-f(z) \right|$ will be, say $\left| f(s)-f(z) \right| = 3 - 2.9999999999 = 0.0000000001$, while $f(t)$ between $f(z)$ and $f(z+\Delta z)$ can be something like $f(t) = 2.9999999998$, correct? But how is, then, $f(t)\le \left| f(s)-f(z) \right|$?

Comment: $\Delta z$ very small. small enough means negligible

Comment: Yes, I understand. But if you draw the same picture I did, it doesn't really matter how small $\Delta z$ is.